# Regular expression taking into account next character

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match our order numbers (always in the format ABC + 6 or 7 digits). e.g ABC123456 or ABC1234567

I have:

```
preg_match_all("/(ABC)([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7})/", $content, $matches);
```

But if somebody quotes to us ABC12345678 then it is extracting ABC1234567. This is incorrect. Instead no match should be found by preg_match_all.

How can I amend the regex to say "All occurrences of ABC followed by 6 or 7 digits. Ignore anything where the character after the 7th character is a number"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
preg_match_all("/(ABC)([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7})(?![0-9])/", $content, $matches);
```

This will match ABC1234567, with anything after the 7 except a digit.

The part before `(?![0-9])` will match only if the part inside of `(?!...)` doesn't match. So if you don't want a letter after the `7` neither, do this:

```
preg_match_all("/(ABC)([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7})(?![0-9a-zA-Z])/", $content, $matches);
```

If you don't want `_` characters either, do this:

```
preg_match_all("/(ABC)([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7})(?![0-9a-zA-Z_])/", $content, $matches);
```

Which is actually equivalent to using `\b`:

```
preg_match_all("/(ABC)([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7})\b/", $content, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if I have applied it correctly though.

"The short one is ABC4444 and then ABC55555 and finally ABC666666 and what about ABC7777777 or even ABC88888888"

With:

    preg_match_all("/(ABC)([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7})(?![0-9])/", $content, $matches);

Is giving me:

    ABC002244 ABC666666 ABC777777 ABC7777777 ABC888888 

Whereas I wouldn't expect ABC888888 to match as this was originally ABC followed by 8 digits.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can combine 6 and 7 digits checks into 1
2. Use word boundaries or input start/end anchors

Use this regex:

```
/\b(ABC)[0-9]{6,7}\b/
```

OR

```
/^(ABC)[0-9]{6,7}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$`, like:

```
preg_match_all("/(ABC)([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7})$/", $content, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the end of word as

```
preg_match_all("/(ABC)([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7}\>)/", $content, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this patterm:

```
^(ABC)\d{6,7}$
```

Here

```
^     = Starts with 
(ABC) = ABC
\d    = followed by digits between 0-9 inclusive.
{6,7} = 6 or 7 times
$     = till the end of the order number
```